# Incorrect Date when changing month

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I have integrated `BsDatepickerModule` from `ngx-bootstrap` in my app module to let user filter a list by date. The problem is when I change month(for example moving from january to february, I'm getting incorrect date(day - 1).

Here is the app module:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [BsDatepickerModule.forRoot() ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is the component:

```
onValueChange(value: Date): void {
    console.log(value.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
});
```

When I change the month and then select for example `2019/01/07` the output print `2019/01/06`

What is wrong ?

Notice that I'm converting the date to get it in format `YYYY-mm-dd`

Comment: I cant remember exactly where the problem lies but this will be to do with an array index starting at 0 and potentially else where being use starting from 1. 0 - 11 in places but 1 -12 in others for months in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is written in the  MDN docs that, monthIndex is 0 based.

So to convert month from Date constructor to human readable month, add 1 to the value.

new Date().getMonth() + 1

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Edit:

Ok I have created a stackblitz demo. Check and see if you want your app to be like this.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z3vtli

Edit 2:

I have updated the demo.
You should not be converting date to toISOString() as it is by default *(I think)*.
Go for toLocalDateString() if you want the same as your local date.

**Credits:**

One of my seniors at work.

@Eliseo *(In the comments section)*

Comment: I don't have issue with months ! It's the day which is lower than the correct one

Comment: the problem is related to the GTM. When you use new Date(year,month,day).you can fall in this problem when you're,e.g. in GTM+2, and you get a day less. If you use new Date(year,month,day,12) you solved the problem

Comment: @Eliseo, can you show a demo of what you just said? Although I think what you said may be correct.

Comment: @AkashPanigrahi, I don't remember if was a problem with an old versions of angular or ngx-bootstrap or another datepicker, but I'am sure I was crazy with the problem

Comment: @Eliseo, so exactly what was the problem? Was the problem with versioning or the GTM issue? Because I think the GTM issue is legit.

Comment: Works great ! Thanks